# Is it possible to use socketCAN protocol on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, can-bus, bus, python-can

I am looking to connect to a car wirelessly using socketCAN protocol on MacOS using the module python-can on python3. I don't know how to install the socketCAN protocol on MacOS. Pls help.

Comment: What CAN adapter do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cat managed to get it basically working:

[socketcanx](https://github.com/duraki/socketcanx/tree/master)

I have compiled it on my hackintosh (running Mojave) and it works from the terminal. I have not played around with it more than that, as it was just easier to use Liunx in a VM or docker or one of my Linux machines. When compiled, I was able to use all of my makeshift CAN devices and a USB2CAN device without issue. I am sure with some work, it can be used with Python-CAN, though you would need to write your own interface module for Python-CAN. As far as I can tell, it should work more or less the same, though the code is old (4 years since last update).

As stated in the accepted answer, you can use a native CAN device that is compatible with macOS and as long as it's compatible with Python-CAN, then you are good to go (or if it works on mac and not compatible, you can create and interface for the device and submit a pull-request on github for Python-CAN).

Comment: Ok, but what does it do? How to use it? Can I use it with PythonCAN or SocketCANSharp?

Answer (score 0):

SocketCAN is implemented only for the Linux kernel. So it is not available on other operating systems. But as long as your CAN adapter is supported by python-can, you don't need SocketCAN.